# nmtui unable to activate wireless connection, nmcli dev status says wifi unavailable

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

I'm very new to using linux. When I try using nmtui to connect to wifi, the only option in "activate a connection" is wired connection. When I use `nmcli dev status`, it outputs `wlo1 wifi unavailable`. Are these things related? How do I connect to wifi?
Additional Info:

- Running Debian 6.1.52
- `nmcli dev status` previously output "unmanaged" instead of "unavailable," which changed after I just went into NetworkManager.conf and changed `managed=false` to `managed=true`
- `nmcli radio` outputs: wifi-hw enabled, wifi enabled, wwan-hw missing, wwan enabled
- I do not have access to an ethernet connection

Answer (score 0):

Try rfkill command!
`sudo rfkill unblock all`
See: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-wifi-interfaces-with-rfkill-command-on-linux